# How to 'git clone --recurse-submodules' a github repo using ssh key, without being asked for username and password?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, ssh-keys

Hello StackOverflow Community Members,

I'm looking for some help 'git clone --recurse-submodules'ing a github repo using an ssh key, without being asked for username and password.

I have no issues cloning repos using a properly setup ssh key:

```
git clone git@github.com:{company_name}/{main_repo}.git
```

Everything works as expected here and project files are retrieved without asking me for a username and password.

This is not the case however when I try to automatically initialize and update each submodule in the repository (per [instructions](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules#:%7E:text=Cloning%20a%20Project%20with%20Submodules&text=If%20you%20pass%20%2D%2Drecurse,the%20repository%20have%20submodules%20themselves.)):

```
git clone --recurse-submodules git@github.com:{company_name}/{main_repo}.git
```

When I run this I am asked for a username and password before any of the submodules are retrieved. This is highly undesired.

Any ideas on why I'm being asked for a username and password when I run with --recurse-submodules?  I have permission to successfully clone the submodule repos individually (without inputing username and password):

```
git clone git@github.com:{company_name}/{submodule_repo}.git
```

Your brilliant assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Hard to say without looking at exact messages Git asked. Most probably it's because some submodules are written in `.gitmodules` with `https://` protocol instead of `ssh://` or `git@`.

In that case use [`git config --global url.<base>.insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) to substitute URLs on the fly. Something like

```
git config --global url.git@github.com:.insteadOf https://github.com/
```

(Please note the colon after `git@github.com:`; it's necessary to map `https://github.com/user/repo.git` to `git@github.com:user/repo.git`).

See more examples in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+insteadof

Comment: Thank you for the response phd. Turns out some admin mods on the submodule permissions were causing the issue (i.e. my permission to access the submodule repos was temporarily removed).

Comment: @CodeTrue Hard to guess.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out some admin mods on the submodule permissions were causing the issue (i.e. my permission to access one of the submodule repos was temporarily removed).